# Install KDE Plasma 5.9 on Debian 8

Tags: debian, plasma5

Is it possible to install KDE Plasma 5.9 on Debian 8 without switching to unstable packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even on unstable, Plasma is still on 5.8 because Stretch is to be released with Plasma 5.8 and bugfixes always comes from experimental / unstable.

You will have to wait until Stretch is released.